# php mysqli binding parameter:No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

ok, this is my codes to bind the parameters dynamically.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `password`, `email`, `permission`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$sql_stmt =  $mysqli->prepare ($sql);

$test = array("ssss","1","2","3","4");

call_user_func_array(array($sql_stmt,'bind_param') ,$test);

$sql_stmt->execute();
```

I get a "No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement" error. However, the following line will work.

```
call_user_func_array(array($sql_stmt,'bind_param') ,array("ssss","1","2","3","4"));
```

I have no idea what is going on here.

**edit**
I just tried doing a

```
echo $sql_stmt->param_count;
```

and I get a proper count of 4.

It will be of great help if I can be enlightened on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the second note in [PHP's page for bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). It says `call_user_func_array()` needs parameters to be passed by reference. So this should work:

```
$arr = array('ssss', '1', '2', '3', '4');
call_user_func_array( array($sql_stmt, 'bind_param'), &$arr );
```

Comment: this line does work.
`call_user_func_array(array($sql_stmt,'bind_param') ,array("ssss","1","2","3","4"));`
its when i try to add it as a variable than it does not work